# Does $f=g$ (a.e.) and $g=h$ (a.e.) imply $f=g$ (a.e.) when the measure is not complete?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(S,\Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space. Let $f,g,h:S\rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be functions. Suppose $f = g$ a.e. and $g = h$ a.e., show that $f = h$ a.e..

**My try:**

I can show the above claim when the measure is complete as follows:

Since $f = g$ a.e., we have $\mu(\{x\in S : f(x) \neq g(x)\}) = 0$. Similarly, since $g = h$ a.e., we have $\mu(\{x\in S : g(x) \neq h(x)\}) = 0$.

Let $E = \{x\in S : f(x) \neq h(x)\}$. Then we have:
\begin{align*}
\mu(E) &= \mu(\{x\in S : f(x) \neq h(x)\}) \\
&= \mu(\{x\in S : f(x) \neq g(x) \text{ or } g(x) \neq h(x)\}) \\
&\leq \mu(\{x\in S : f(x) \neq g(x)\}) + \mu(\{x\in S : g(x) \neq h(x)\}) \\
&= 0 + 0 = 0.
\end{align*}
Therefore, we have $\mu(E) = 0$, which implies that $f = h$ almost everywhere on $S$.

**Question**

I am not sure what I should do when the measure is not complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, when we say that a statement $P(x)$ holds almost everywhere, we do not require for the set $\{x \in S : \neg P(x)\}$ to be measurable. We merely assume that there is a (measurable) set $N$ such that $\mu(N) = 0$ and $P(x)$ holds for all $x \notin N$.

In particular, if $f=g$ and $g=h$ both hold almost everywhere, then define $N_{fg}$ and $N_{gh}$ to be sets of measure $0$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x \notin N_{fg}$ and $g(x) = h(x)$ for all $x \notin N_{gh}$. Then, as argued in the question, we have $f(x) = h(x)$ for all $x \notin N_{fg} \cup N_{gh}$, and $$\mu(N_{fg} \cup N_{gh}) \le \mu(N_{fg}) + \mu(N_{gh}) = 0 + 0 = 0.$$ This suffices, since $N_{fg} \cup N_{gh}$ is certainly measurable (even though the set $\{x \in S : f(x) \ne h(x)\}$ might not be).

Comment: Is $N_{fg}$ and $N_{gh}$ are the ones that I have defined?

Comment: Not necessarily; unless $f,g,h$ are measurable functions (which we don't need to assume), the set $\{x \in S: f(x) \ne g(x)\}$ might not be measurable either. What we know is that if $f=g$ almost everywhere, then the set $\{x \in S: f(x) \ne g(x)\}$ is *contained* in some set $N_{fg}$ of measure $0$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with a complete measure, as say $f=g$ on $N_1^c$ and $g=h$ on $N_2^c$. Then  $N_1^c\cap N_2^c \subseteq A = \{x \in S: f(x)=h(x)\}$, where $A \in \Sigma$. Hence $A^c \in \Sigma$ and as $A^c \subseteq N_1\cup N_2$, it has measure zero.

Comment: I am not getting what you are trying to say. Can you explain what you are trying to convey? And, what is the message of your post?

Comment: The basic gist is that $\{x \in S: f(x)\not= h(x)\}$ is measurable in any measure space, hence you can safely conclude it has measure zero.

Comment: My question is with regard to $A=\{x\in S : f(x) \neq g(x)\}$ where $\mu(A) = 0$. What if there is $B \subset A$ whose measure is not zero? What should I do then?

Comment: I don't quite understand